# Print a character to start of every line in Python

Tags: python

I'm wishing to print a character to the start of every line in python code. In particular, I want to print a "|" to the start of every outputted line. What would be the best way to achieve this in python?

Answer (score 1):

Using Python 3? Replace `print`:

```
_realprint = print
def print(*args, **kwargs):
    _realprint('|', end='')
    _realprint(*args, **kwargs)
print.__doc__ = _realprint.__doc__
```

Now everything output by `print` will be prefixed by '|'. Extra credit for replacing `\n` with `\n|` in your `_realprint()` calls, remembering when called with `end` equal to something other than `\n`, etc. This should get you through 99% of cases, though.

Comment: Is it possible to specify for specific lines this will apply. I want the majority of lines to include the prefix, but some not to.

Comment: You could, but you're going to have to write **something** to specify it.... and the amount of effort required to "write something" to just specify outputting the `'|'` directly is so tiny that I'd just do that directly.

Answer (score 0):

Make your own file-like that defines `write()` and replace `sys.stdout`.

```
import sys

class forewrap(object):
  def __init__(self, origfile, cseq='|'):
    self.file = origfile
    self.cseq = cseq
    self.seen = False

  def write(self, txt):
    if not (self.seen and txt == '\n'):
      self.seen = True
      self.file.write(self.cseq)
    else:
      self.seen = False
    self.file.write(txt)

print 'foo'
sys.stdout = forewrap(sys.stdout)
print 'foo'
print
print 'bar'
```